# What is a name of a ^ a>>4 ^ a>>9 ^ a>>15 ^ a>>22 hash function?

Tags: algorithm, hash, xor, shift

What is the type and name of a ^ a>>4 ^ a>>9 ^ a>>15 ^ a>>22 hash function?
Where I can read about one or similar?